# Renaming the index in a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, series

For the past few hours, I've been trying to change/rename the name of my multiindex in my pandas Series but I do not know how to achieve it. I've been looking all kind of different things and I cannot seem to get it right. This is important because I have realized that if I do not do so, my two indexes have the same name (which is "date"). Here is the code:

```
df_bar = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = "Y"), pd.Grouper(freq = "M")])["value"].mean()
```

if you print df_bar, you would have the following:
[print of df_bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtxNy.png)

Would it be possible to name each index directly in the groupby()?

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not, need rename in next step by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
   {
       "date": [
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-02"),
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-02"),
            pd.Timestamp("2001-01-09"),
            pd.Timestamp("2001-01-16")
        ],
        "value": [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }

).set_index('date')

df_bar = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = "Y"), pd.Grouper(freq = "M")])["value"]
            .mean()
            .rename_axis(['Y','M']))
print (df_bar)
Y           M         
2000-12-31  2000-01-31    15
2001-12-31  2001-01-31    35
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That worked just fine, cheers :) Damn I feel stupid seeing just how easy the code was

Comment: @EnekoCUBILLASLAISECA - Sometimes working `name` parameter, but here not, `pd.Grouper(freq = "Y", name='Y')` failed.

Comment: That is what I tried once and it did not work :D